# LIBCURL C SFTP Authentication with both public key and password

Tags: passwords, sftp, libcurl, public-key

I am developing an C/C++ application that performs file transfers using SFTP protocol with lib-curl. However, I am facing an specific problem that an remote host is requires **both** public-key and user password authentication in two steps.

How should I configure the CURLOPT parameters in this scenario? I am currently implementing something like this in my application:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, myurl.Str);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &sftpfile);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES, CURLSSH_AUTH_ANY);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, sUser.Str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "sUserPassword.Str()");
if (!sPrivateKeyFile.IsEmptyString()) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE, sPrivateKeyFile.Str());
}
if (!sPublicKeyFile.IsEmptyString()) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE, sPublicKeyFile.Str());
}
if (!sKnownHosts.IsEmptyString()) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS, sKnownHostsFile.Str());
}
if (!sPassword.IsEmptyString()) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, sPassword.Str());
}
#ifdef _CURL_VERBOSE
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
#endif
```

When I run my application, I noticed that the PEM key-pair is read successfully and I am getting curl failure 67 authentication message.

I am wondering if libcurl supports authentication by using both public-key and user password authentication in two steps.

Best regards,

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?  If so could you let me know how.   Or post your own answer.

Comment: No, I did not solve this issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the private key only the public key in your .ssh directory.
I do not understand why you say it's a two step process.
All you need is the host fingerprint or use `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` to skip the verification.

Last night I was trying to do the same thing in PHP with curl.
I got it working.
This app just reads the files in the folder.
I will soon (today) have the curl write file app.

My problem was the host had the user and password.

```
$url = "sftp://$user:$password@$host";
```

I moved the user name and password to `CURLOPT_USERPWD`

```
$host = "72.000.000.111/home/user/public_html/";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass!";

$url = "sftp://@$host";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, '1L');// just want file names
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "error: $error<br>\n";
echo "response <PRE>$response<br>";
```

In looking for a solution there were some that solved it by doing the opposite. The went from `CURLOPT_USERPWD` to sftp://user:pass@host
Guess it depends on the SFTP server.

One of the things I found problematic is the public key. 
That is the reading of the public key to verify the source location.

For may app that was not that important to me. 
So I just did not verify the host `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)`. 
I could have added the host to .ssh but I needed the MD5 to created the .ppk and only had the SHA256 fingerprint. So I skipped the host verification.
I believe this is the only step you need too.

On my Win10 Workstation all I had to do was use FileZilla to connect and click the "Always trust this host, add this key to the cache" checkbox.

So I am pretty sure you just need the MD5 fingerprint.
Make a .ppk file from the fingerprint.
And put the .ppk in the .ssh directory. 
And probably eliminate some of the CURLOPTs.